# Iteration of strings inside my arraylist to textview not working

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Hi I want to set the text of my textview according the the data i got from my arraylist from my JSONObject. But my app stops working when i try to iterate my arraylist to my textview. Can you guys help me with my problem. Thaaanks! Here is my code. Thanks

```
            AsyncClass taskSpecialty = new AsyncClass(DetailActivity.this, postData, false, new AsyncResponse() {
            @Override
            public void processFinish(String s) {
                Log.d("DetailAcitivty", s);
                try {
                    JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(s);
                    JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("result");

                    StringBuffer finalBufferedData = new StringBuffer();
                    for (int i=0 ; i<parentArray.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String spcltID = finalObject.getString("sName");
                        finalBufferedData.append(spcltID + "\n");
                    }
                    ArrayList<String> listdata = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for(int i =0; i<parentArray.length(); i++){
                        listdata.add(parentArray.getString(i));
                    }
                    LinearLayout llSpecialty = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llSpecialty);

                    Iterator<String> iterator = listdata.iterator();
                    while (iterator.hasNext()){
                        TextView textView = new TextView(DetailActivity.this);
                        textView.setText(listdata.get(1));
                        llSpecialty.addView(textView);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        taskSpecialty.execute("http://10.0.2.2/wingman/specialty.php");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `iterator.next()` in while loop.

```
textView.setText(iterator.next());
```

Comment: Okay ill try it.

Comment: Thanks it worked but I have one more problem. The `listdata.get(1)` is not working and it still set text textview to the whole arraylist...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as following:

```
String str="";
while (iterator.hasNext()){
     TextView textView = new TextView(DetailActivity.this);
     str+=iterator.next();
     llSpecialty.addView(textView);
}

textView.setText(str);
```